# Cannot map an item in a list to a list in list of lists

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have two lists like so,

```
  list1 = ['a','b','c','d']
  list2 = [[20,30,15], [23,32,62,234, 234], [34,345,5345], [12]]
```

How can I map them so it outputs:

```
   a 20
   a 30
   a 15

   b 23
   b 32
   b 62
   .
   .
   .
   d 12
```

I tried this

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
list2 = [[20, 30, 15], [23, 32, 62, 234, 234], [34, 345, 5345], [12]]
for item in list2:
    for al, it, in zip(list1, item):
        print(al, it)
```

which gives

```
a 20
b 30
c 15
a 23
b 32
c 62
d 234
a 34
b 345
c 5345
a 12
```

Comment: Is this okay for you : `[list(zip(list(item[0]*len(item[1])), item[1])) for item in list(zip(list1, list2))]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `enumerate()`:

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
list2 = [[20, 30, 15], [23, 32, 62, 234, 234], [34, 345, 5345], [12]]
for index, alpha in enumerate(list1):
    for number in list2[index]:
        print(alpha, number)
```